# Still receiving push notifications after revoking APNs cert

Tags: ios, push

My APNs cert is expiring soon so I revoked the APNs cert (just to make sure everything is working fine). But after 30 min I am still receiving testing push notifications. Is it because of Apple's cache? How long will it last?

Comment: Have you replaced the old certificate with newly generated one in server?

Comment: Yes, my actions are:
1. Revoke APNs cert of the app (production)
2. Send test push from server
3. App can still receive pushes (after 2 hours)

Comment: So you mentioned that you have replaced the old cert with new one. So the server sends push notification with new certificate.

Comment: No I did not mention I replaced old cert. And I didn't.

Comment: But for my first comment, you said yes...So your actions are 1. Revoked the cert 2. Sending test push with revoked cert 3. App receives the notification even after 2hours am I correct?

Comment: Oh sorry please ignore the 'Yes'... You description of my steps are correct.

Comment: Please make sure have you revoked the APN cert or distribution/ development? Because sending push notification after revoking the cert is not possible. developer.apple.com/support/technical/certificates

Comment: I'll just add that I'm experiencing this situation too. Revoked all development and production APNS certificates but pushes still successfully arrive at devices with the revoked certificate. Has been 24 hours now.

Answer (score 1):

Your old certificate is not expired yet from your question. So If your server uses the same cert, your existing iOS application will receive push notification. **You should replace the old cert with new one.**

Comment: Hi Jailani, yes my server is using old p12 file. So it means revoking the cert from developer portal does not invalidate the cert/p12? Is there any documentation on this? Thanks!

Comment: Please make sure have you revoked the APN cert or distribution/ development? Because sending push notification after revoking the cert is not possible. https://developer.apple.com/support/technical/certificates/

Answer (score 0):

Usually, it will take 24 Hrs to reflect APNS Certificate revoke! - After that you will get SSLException with "certificate_revoked" .